# Jquery: ".fadeIn('slow')" not loading <tbody> properly in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table, which I have divided in 2 parts `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. 
`<thead>` displays on page all the time whereas the `<tbody>` is set to "`display:none`" and it loads with some content on click of a button.

For loading the `<tbody>` I am using "Jquery: .fadeIn()" method. below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $( ".applicationTable tbody" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
});
```

The issue is, that on Firefox and Chrome, the `<tbody>` loads smoothly with fading effect, where as in IE (I am checking on IE11), its flickers.

**Here is the Fiddle for the complete code (HTML CSS and Jquery): http://jsfiddle.net/9Bpry/1/**

Please check this fiddle in all 3 browsers "Chrome, Firefox and IE" to see the difference.

And please suggest how can I fix this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you just love internet exploder?

Comment: Applying effects to anything inside of tables besides `<table>` and `<td>` is not guaranteed to work correctly because of the limited styling options supported. Which IE are you referring to anyways?

Comment: I am checking on IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from IE's limited styling options for tables and their child tags. No amount of jQuerying is going to be 100%

I would suggest this structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;">something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $( ".applicationTable tbody td" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

let me share some tests from about 2-3 years ago.

I tested similar thing (trying to slideUp/slideDown a 'tr' using jQuery) on previous IE versions (IE7 and below, not sure about IE8) and I can tell you that under IE it's impossible to have such effects for tables.

You could use the effect in all browsers except IE and use show/hide for IE, or alternatively you can use div-s for markup and then you can have all effects needed (note: it could be very tricky if you have different background for each row and/or have different images in the cells).

Let me say it again - it's very well tested for older IE versions and didn't work, but if anyone else have experience in the past version of IE, then you can just omit my answer (keep it it mind if you need browser compatibility).